# SQL OUTER JOIN query is asking for parameter when ran in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to emulate a Vlookup by joining tables together if they share the same string. However every field that I include is prompting the enter parameter box to appear and I cannot understand why.
Below I have the two tables that I need to get data from. Please note that there are some fields that I do not require for this query so have been filled in with dummy data.

**Details**

| SourceCode | F1 | F2 | NewMinorCat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1077 | test | test | UNP |
| 5141 | test | test | GUU |
| 887 | test | test | XPR |
| 584 | test | test | FGG |
| 444 | test | test | IIU |
| 5141 | test | test | GUU |

**Leads**

| date_value | Booked_vist | Completed_visit | marketing_event_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | test | test | 5141 |
| 10/02/2022 | test | test | 444 |
| 30/04/2022 | test | test | 887 |
| 05/03/2022 | test | test | 887 |
| 17/07/2021 | test | test | 1077 |

I am aiming to get the NewMinorCat placed into the rows where the SourceCode and marketing_event_id match. Something like this structure:

**Output**

| date_value | marketing_event_id | NewMinorCat |
| --- | --- | --- |

The code I've got so far through looking around for solutions that I have then changed.

```
SELECT Leads.marketing_event_id, Details.SourceCode, Details.NewMinorCat
FROM Leads AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Details as T2
ON T1.marketing_event_id = T2.SourceCode
```

I imagine that it is an oversight on my part but for the life of me I cannot see why it will work with one DB but not with the one I need.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T1.market_event_id is a column that does not exists (it's called "market**ing**_event_id" in your example)

Comment: I had just seen that, but even after fixing the typo the result remains the same.

Comment: once you define an alias (T1, T2) keep using it and don'T refer to the table name anymore. "SELECT T1.marketing_event_id, T2.SourceCode, T2.NewMinorCat
FROM ..."

Comment: Thank you. That was it, no idea why I was using the aliases after the SELECT statement but it is now working as intended, thank you once again.